# Solution verification of boundedness of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can anyone verify my solution?

Let $T_n : \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ given by $$T_n(x) = \left(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\dots,\frac{x_n}{n},0,\dots\right).$$

We prove $T_n$ is bounded for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $x \in \ell^2$. Then \begin{align}
  \|T_nx\|_2 & = \|(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\dots,\frac{x_n}{n},0,\dots)\|_2\\
  & = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|\frac{x_i}{i}\right|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
  & = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{|i|^2}|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
  & \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
  & = \|x\|_2.
 \end{align}

**Remark**: Notice that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have a finite sum. I believe we don't even need this observation to prove the result.

Comment: It is fine. You can allow infinite sums i.e. $T_\infty.$ Moreover $\|T_n\|=1$ as $T_n\delta_1=\delta_1,$ where $\delta_1$ denotes the sequence $(1,0,0,\ldots ).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Indeed, it won't change. Thanks for the extension on the problem!